# What is the function of this Drasha?

Tags: talmud-gemara, midrash, tractate-brachot, shalom-peace

Brachos 64a:

> אמר רבי אלעזר אמר רבי חנינא תלמידי חכמים מרבים שלום בעולם
>   שנאמר
>   (ישעיהו נד, יג) "וכל בניך למודי ה' ורב שלום בניך"
>   אל תקרי בניך אלא בוניך

What is the function of this Al Tikrei? The pshat of the pasuk does a fine job of proving the tannah's assertion. What does the Al Tikrei come to add?

Comment: Personally I would ask the opposite; even after the al tikrei, the point is still not really demonstrated.

Comment: http://tora.us.fm/tnk1/nvia/yjayhu/yj-54-13.html

Comment: בוניך may mean "those who understand You" @mevaqesh

Comment: One possibility is that since the children of God who know him are interpreted as being Torah scholars, there is no proof that they bring peace to the world; just to the children as it says ורב שלום בניך. Therefore, the second appearance of the word בניך is interpreted as referring to builders; that is, someone who is a group that obviously not referring to torah scholars, to demonstrate that they bring peace to the whole world.

Comment: Can you explain what is the pshat without al tikre. If this pshat has a Kashia, so the al tikre is a teruts. I feel that if you explain the pshat before the Drasha, it would be easier to discuss on your question.

Comment: The Maharsha asks your question, but not in Brachos. Check where else this gemara appears.

Comment: @mevaqesh, probably not builders, but understanders (see wfb's [comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71574/what-is-the-function-of-this-drasha#comment209316_71574) - ie., scholars. But your second point is taken: without the Derashah, it seems only to be speaking about children who have/receive/give/increase peace.

Comment: @SethJ very good pshat so that is the proof that TC are the "בניך" and not someone other. It may be a good answer

Answer (score 2):

I thought [this](http://tora.us.fm/tnk1/nvia/yjayhu/yj-54-13.html) was an interesting *pshat* from Erel Segal-Halevi ([a fellow *Yodeyan*!](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1332/erel-segal-halevi)).

In context, the *psukim* ([Yeshayahu 54:11-17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1054.htm#11)) are talking about building Jerusalem. So *bonayikh* means the builders of Jerusalem. Later on ([Yeshayahu 60:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1060.htm#10)), the *pasuk* says

> וּבָנוּ בְנֵי-נֵכָר חֹמֹתַיִךְ
>
> And aliens shall build up thy walls

From this, we learn that non-Jews will be among the builders of Jerusalem.

So while we might have thought that our *pasuk* was saying that the children of Hashem would become learned in God's Torah and therefore *they* would have a great peace, instead, read the second בניך as בוניך, "your builders". That includes the non-Jews as we learned from *perek* 60. Learning Torah doesn't just cause שלום for the Jews; it causes שלום בעולם.

If we had read the second בניך as it's written, we would have thought the *pasuk* was only implying peace for the Jewish people and therefore it would not prove R' Chaninah's point.

Comment: This is essentially the answer I suggested in the comments; it just widens the scope of בוניך from non-scholars to non-Jews.

Answer (score 1):

The emphasis of the drosh is on *scholars* in particular, bringing peace to the world, and there was already an established metaphor likening scholars to builders - see the Mishna, [Mikvaot 9:6](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Mikvaot.9.6), where "בנאים" is constrasted with "בור" (and [the Bartenura there](http://www.sefaria.org/Bartenura_on_Mishnah_Mikvaot.9.6.2), who explains).

Comment: "to the world in particular" as opposed to what? Something broader than the world?

Comment: @mevaqesh - no, as in *scholars* in particular. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: I edited it; change it back if you dont like it of course.